# Tomcat in Intellij Idea Community Edition (port not recognized)

Tags: java, tomcat

The program starts to work, but an error is issued, and at the moment the process is looping when the protocol starts. Help finish the installation of tomcat.

[pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAzvV.jpg)

[continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt8fy.jpg)

[continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjDjG.jpg)

[error and result message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/836R6.jpg)

Comment: Please add the important parts of your question not only as Image but in an code block as formatted Text. This way it can be found via the Search engines and is much more readable

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the context path. As you can notice in the log, there is a line that says: `context path must start with /`. The URL of your application is `http://localhost:8080SampleProject`. It has to be `http://localhost:8080/SampleProject` or `http://localhost:8080/`.

To do this, in the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` in the `pom.xml`, change the parameter `path` value into '/SampleProject' instead of 'SampleProject'

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml your tomcat path has to start with an `/`.

Change `<path>SampleProject</path>` to `<path>/SampleProject</path>` and it will start under `http://localhost:8080/SampleProject`